# Whose semicha (ordination) was the last one signed/granted by Rabbi Joseph Dov Soloveichik?  By Rabbi Moshe Feinstein?

Tags: history, rabbis, moshe-feinstein, rav-joseph-ber-soloveitchik, semicha

Whose semicha (ordination) was the last one signed/granted by Rabbi Joseph Dov Soloveichik?  What about by Rabbi Moshe Feinstein?

(The answer may be "the yeshiva ABC class of 1981" or whatever.)

Comment: I wonder in anyone knows this answer. Maybe there are those that know who was the first Semicha given by these Rabbis.

Comment: It shouldn't be  too hard for a YU historian to determine which graduating class of RIETS was the last to have Rabbi Soloveichik signing all the semicha certificates.

Comment: I'm just fascinated as to why anyone would *care* about the answer to this question.  Are you just trying to "seed" the site with questions...?  ;)

Comment: Is this on topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rabbi Harry Lax was the last recipient of smicha from Rabbi Soloveichik.  I was told this by a great-nephew of Rabbi Soloveichik, who I know from Kehliath Jeshurun synagogue in Manhattan.

Comment: What year was Rabbi Lax ordained? Was it a private or institutional (RIETS) semicha? This bio says he was ordained by RM"F, but I take it RYBS too? http://www.kashrusmagazine.com/ksg/Old%20and%20deleted/ksg_bios.html

Comment: it was done privately

Comment: Jggreenblatt, Please [edit] your answer to include your source for this historical fact, even if it's as simple as "I heard it from my friend."

Comment: ok her is no public historical fact this is not something i quoted from a gammara or a mishna this is just a fact

Comment: @Shalom, are you sure the facts contained in the latter sentence are intended to be related contingently?

Comment: @WAF, Jggreenblatt had written: "The source for this is the grand nephew of the Rav, who is sitting right next to me. And I go to a shul called KJ in Manhattan associated with Ramaz." How would you read that?

Comment: @Shalom, sorry. That was my doing. I was trying to be as uninvasive as possible into the original text. See previous revision.